# Trouble finding the integral curves of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to verify that $ C1=x/(x+y+z) $ and $ C2=y^2-z^2 $ are the integral curves of the PDE

$ x∂z/∂x + z∂z/∂y = y $

I already verified that C2 is (using method of characteristic curves) by solving

$ ∂y/z=∂z/y $

but when i try solving

$ ∂x/x=∂z/sqrt(C2+z^2) $

the result is something that has nothing to do with C1, the result is

$ C1=ln(x)-(arctan(z/(y^2-z^2))/sqrt(y^2-z^2) $

How can i get C1? I also tried solving $ ∂x/x=∂y/sqrt(y^2-C2) $ but the result is something with exponentials

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=y$$
System of characteristic ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange) :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from 
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}=\frac{dx+dy+dz}{x+y+z}=\frac{d(x+y+z)}{(x+y+z)} \tag {Note below}$$
Solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{d(x+y+z)}{(x+y+z)}$leads to $\ln|x|=\ln|x+y+z|+$constant.
$$\frac{x}{x+y+z}=C_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}$ :
$$y^2-z^2=C_2$$

NOTE : Remember a wellknown property of fractions :
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}\quad\implies\quad \frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C+c_3E}{c_1B+c_2D+c_3F}$$
for arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ not all nul.

Another (but equivalent method) :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}=dt \quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
dx=x\:dt\\ dy=z\:dt\\ dz=y\:dt
\end{cases}  \quad\implies\quad dx+dy+dz=xdt+zdt+ydt$$
$$d(x+y+z)=(x+y+z)dt=(x+y+z)\frac{dx}{x}  \quad\implies\quad \frac{d(x+y+z)}{(x+y+z)}=\frac{dx}{x}$$